# Evaluate $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^5 2^n \binom{3 n}{n}}$ in terms of elementary constants

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

How can we evaluate
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^5 2^n \binom{3 n}{n}}$$

Related: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^4 2^n \binom{3 n}{n}}$ is solved recently (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3602966/a-suprising-conjectural-closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n4-2n) for the solution) by elementary method, so I wonder if a generalization to weight $5$ can be made.

Comment: Assuming no typo, the imaginary part of the desired series vanishes, which is quite interesting I believe.

Comment: The sum is a special value of a double polylogarithm. Is this on your list of known special functions?

Comment: your minor problem is related to the integral $\Re\int_0^{\frac{1+i}{2}}\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beta+IBP $3$ times+log factorization yields

- $S=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^5 2^n \binom{3 n}{n}}=\int_0^1 \frac2x \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{x^2(1-x)}2\right) dx\\ =\int_0^1 -\frac{2\left((3 x-2) \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2} (1-x) x^2\right)\right) \log (x)}{(x-1) x}  dx\\ =\int_0^1 \frac{2\left((3 x-2) \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2} (1-x) x^2\right)\right) \left(\log ^2(x)-\text{Li}_2(1-x)\right)}{(x-1) x}  dx\\ =\int_0^1 \left(\frac{2}{x}-\frac{1}{1-x}\right) f(x) \left(\log \left((1-x)^2+1\right)+\log (x+1)-\log (2)\right) dx$

Where

- $\small f(x)=2\left(-\text{Li}_3(1-x)+2 \text{Li}_3(x)-2 \text{Li}_2(1-x) \log (x)-2 \text{Li}_2(x) \log (x)+\frac{2 \log ^3(x)}{3}-\log (1-x) \log ^2(x)\right)$

Apply reflection one obtain

- $S=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{2 f(1-x) \left(\log \left(x^2+1\right)-\log (2)\right)}{1-x}-\frac{f(1-x) \log \left(x^2+1\right)}{x}+\frac{2 f(x) \log (x+1)}{x}-\frac{f(x) (\log (x+1)-\log (2))}{1-x}\right) \, dx$

Which has *$4$-admmisible* integrand thus solvable via MZVs of level $4$ (see arXiv $2007.03957$)

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^5 2^n \binom{3 n}{n}}=3 \pi  \beta (4)+4 \pi  \operatorname{Im} \left(\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{51 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}-15 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)+\frac{\pi ^2 \zeta (3)}{4}+\frac{9 \zeta (5)}{2}-3 \zeta (3) \log ^2(2)-\frac{97 \log ^5(2)}{240}+\frac{41}{144} \pi ^2 \log ^3(2)-\frac{61}{960} \pi ^4 \log (2)$$

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but an approach to how one could find your sum in principle.

As I see it, it all comes down to finding a generating function for
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n x^n}{n^4}. \tag1$$
Once found, substituting $x = (1 + i)/2$ into it and taking the real part should deliver the result.

Can this generating function actually be found I do not know. One attempt (which is incorrect) to find it can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908108/how-to-find-large-int-01-frac-ln31x-ln-xx-mathrm-dx/910842#910842) under Eq. (4). I expect such an expression to contain polylogarithmic terms up to order five. I am not sure
$$\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1 + i}{2} \right ),$$
is reducible to more fundamental constants like $\pi$, $\zeta (3)$, $\log (2)$, $\operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right )$, let alone
$$\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_5 \left (\frac{1 + i}{2} \right ).$$

So it boils down to, is it possible to find the generating function for (1)?

**Update**

$\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1 + i}{2} \right )$ is reducible to more fundamental constants. Here
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1 + i}{2} \right ) &= \frac{5}{16} \operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) + \frac{343}{1024} \zeta (4) - \frac{5}{128} \zeta (2) \log^2 (2) + \frac{1}{96} \log^4 (2)\\
&=\frac{5}{16} \operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) + \frac{343 \pi^4}{92160} - \frac{5 \pi^2}{768} \log^2 (2) + \frac{1}{96} \log^4 (2).
\end{align}
This value can be found in the paper given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.12155).

Comment: @ omegadot Are you sure that we have $H_4(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_{n} \frac{z^n}{n^4}$? And if so, where can I find the expression? Wasn't the answer of Tunk-Fey proved wrong? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze - It is listed under Eq. (4) in his solution. I have not checked if the expression he gives is correct but judging from the comments below his answer it seems it is not. I have updated my solution to reflect this.

Comment: @ omegadot you can easyliy falsify the formula of Tunk Fey for $H_4$ by considering his expression in the vicinity of the origin which is a logarithmic divergence proportional to $\log(x)$ whereas is should be analytic starting as $x + \frac{x^2}{2^5} $

Comment: @Display name - Just found the value for $\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_4$ in your wonderful paper. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means a solution but an extended comment which shows that this sum - generalized to a generating function - belongs to the well-known class of special functions, the hypergeometric functions. Maybe this can be of some use.

Defining the generating function

$$g(q,z) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{z^n}{n^q\binom{3 n}{n} }\tag{1}$$

the left hand side of the identity in question is the generating function for $q=5$ at the point $z=\frac{1}{2}$.

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^5 2^n \binom{3 n}{n}} = g(5,\frac{1}{2})\tag{2}$$

We have

$$g(0,z)= \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{z^n}{\binom{3 n}{n}}=\frac{z}{3} \;  _3F_2\left(1,\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3};\frac{4 z}{27}\right)\tag{3}$$

and, recursively, with the indefinite integral

$$g(q+1,z)=\int \frac{1}{z} g(q,z)\,dz\tag{4}$$

Explicitly,

$\begin{align}
& g(1,z) = \frac{z}{3} \; _3F_2\left(1,1,\frac{3}{2};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3};\frac{4 z}{27}\right)\\\\
& g(2,z) =\frac{z}{3}  \; _4F_3\left(1,1,1,\frac{3}{2};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3},2;\frac{4 z}{27}\right)\\\\
&g(3,z)= \frac{z}{3} \; _5F_4\left(1,1,1,1,\frac{3}{2};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3},2,2;\frac{4 z}{27}\right)\\\\
\ldots\\\\
& g(q,z) =\frac{z}{3}  \; _P F_Q\left(1_{1},1_{2},1_{3},\ldots,1_{q+1},\frac{3}{2};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3},2_{1},2_{2},\ldots,2_{q-1};\frac{4 z}{27}\right), \\\\
& P=q+2, Q=q+1\\
\end{align}\tag{5}$

In the end we are interested in these functions at $z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Hopefully there are some means of expanding these hypergeometric functions in terms of the more common function types like zeta, polylog, polygamma (specifically harmonic number).

**Extension**

Similarly we can study the family of sums

$$g_{k,q}(z)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^q} \frac{z^n}{\binom{k\; n}{n}}\tag{6}$$

These generating functions are also expressible in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: I always wondered why some non-elementary functions are considered to be more "elementary" than the others. For example why the hypergeometric function is not so "nice" as the polylog or polygamma ones. :)

Comment: Isn't it absolutely common in mathematics that from some point of the value of a certain parameter an expression cannot be expressed by a standard set of elementary expression? Think of the roots of polynomials which are not expressable in general by radicals if the degreee exceeds 5. But in this example there is a non-existence proof which, as far as I know, is not availble for the problem of the OP.